# permission issues when installing django/creating virtualenv on MAC

Tags: python, virtualenv

This is the response issue when i try to install it ..

> ```
> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13]
> Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.pyc'
> Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
> ```

Was wondering how I could fix this and make it automatic so that i don't get permission issues.

Comment: Did you consider using the `--user` option?

Comment: This question already has an answer on SO, I guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504231/whats-causing-this-error-when-i-try-and-install-virtualenv-ioerror-errno-13

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong on this one, since I stopped using Mac some months ago and therefor I cannot check it myself, but just typing `sudo` before the command could work. Let us know if that works.